# tramp-default-method has no effect

Tags: tramp, customize, ssh

I have a config file to setup defaults for tramp.  For the purposes of this example `foo` and `bar` are hosts defined in `/etc/hosts`.

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-user-alist
             '("ssh" "foo" "user1"))
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-user-alist
             '("ssh" nil "user2") t)
```

From [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc1) link I expect to then be able to use the following shorthand:

eg1 - load `filename` from `user1@foo`

`C-x C-f /foo:filename` rather than `C-x C-f /ssh:user1@foo:filename`

eg2 - load `filename` from `user2@any_server`, here we've picked `bar`

`C-x C-f /bar:filename` rather than `C-x C-f /ssh:user2@bar:filename`

Both of the left-hand shorthands fail on typing `C-x C-f /foo:` - options given suggest that Emacs has not recognized `foo` as a server (perhaps it's recognizing it as a connection method?).

Both of the right-hand long-winded versions work, as does the following:

`C-x C-f /ssh:foo:filename`

i.e. Tramp is correctly finding the default `user1`, but seems not to find the default connection type of `ssh`.

I've tried running Emacs as `emacs --no-init-file` to make sure it's not something in my init file. But doing that, and loading only the Tramp settings manually, the issue is identical.

As a final attempt I tried adding to `tramp-default-method-alist` instead.

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-method-alist
             '(nil nil "ssh"))
```

And also this:

```
(customize-set-variable 'tramp-default-method "ssh")
```

These don't work either - although in every case I do see the variable has been set with `M-x Customize`.

I'm using 26.1 with built-in tramp on Ubuntu 18.04:

`tramp 2.3.3.26.1 built-in Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocol`

I'm probably missing something obvious, given it's such a simple thing to setup!  Can anyone point me in the right direction - it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Tramp 2.3 / Emacs 26.1, Tramp's syntax has changed. It requires now the method name mandatory. If you want the shorter version of Tramp file names (without the method), you must change the syntax via the command `tramp-change-syntax syntax`. See the Tramp manual, section `Alternative file name syntax`.

Comment: Thanks, for those yearning the old-ways you can add this to your start-up or change it directly in session `(customize-set-variable 'tramp-syntax 'simplified)`